DB2 RESTORE on new server affects database on original server
My question is pretty simple: Can a DB2 RESTORE on one server, affect the server where the backup originated? That is, can the DB2 RESTORE command contact the original server and do "something" because it stores server name and DB credentials in the backup?
I'm using DB2 for Windows, v11.1 on SERVER1 and v11.5 FP9 on SERVER 2. I'm doing this to establish a test-system on a separate server with the production data.
The sequence of events was as following:

I do a DB2 BACKUP on SERVER1
I copy the backup files to SERVER2
I do a DB2 RESTORE on SERVER2

At the EXACT same moment I start the DB2 RESTORE on SERVER2, I start getting the following errors in db2diag on SERVER1:

Password validation for user db2admin failed with rc = -2146500483

I'm quite lost here and have halted the process for now.
One theory I have is that both DB2 installations are residing on the same SAN, and maybe the DB2 RESTORE is so intensive, that it disrupts the operation of the SERVER1 DB2.
Thanks,
/Morten.

is db2admin a local or Active Directory account ?

You are definitely on to something. I found out that the db2admin domain account had been locked (I just didn't see it because it automatically auto-unlocked). Even though the new test system runs on a local windows account with the same name, it somehow contacts the domain and tries to log on with another password and the gets the db2admin user account locked. I'll post an answer when I have more information.

you should change the AD policy for db2admin to disable the locking of that account. other wize any one can DoS your db2 instance

No, RESTORE will not "contact the original server", and no, the backup does not contain "server name and DB credentials". Look elsewhere.
